# How to load packages in R?

Tags: r, install.packages

Please bear in mind that my laptop is from non-English country and previously I had a problem to install packages in R, but I have figured out by using

```
install.packages('R330', lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/win-library")
```

And as I uploaded the photo below, it successfully imported all packages in my laptop to the address.

[image: installed packages]

However, now when I try to load packages, it shows an error saying like

[image: error message]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the packages in the same directory, install all of them by:

```
setwd("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/win-library") 
pkgs <- list.files()

install.packages(c(print(as.character(pkgs), collapse="\",\"")), repos = NULL)
```

The error you're getting is because `s20x` hasn't been installed.